# How to create a UML use case diagram that has multiple options for the same use case?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

so I had this situation where this User(Customer) need to choose between yes or no option for buying a movie ticket option, and then they need to choose again between food choice rather customer want to buy food or drink, I know about use case diagram but it's confused me about the "Option" especially multiple options (because on use-case diagram there is no triangle type thing right(option thing on different UML, I forgot the name of it)),

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

In your narrative, there is only one use-case: `Buy a movie ticket`;  this is the **actor goal**.  The fact that there are options are just details of this use-case.

Moreover, use-cases do not show anything about a sequence. If you want to show this kind of logic, you could consider an [**activity diagram**](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-activity-diagram/) with decision nodes and different **flow** of control or of objects and actions depending on the choices made.

But if you do so, you have already taken position on the user interface. But user interfaces are not well designed in UML. They are best addressed with [UX design techniques](https://stephaniewalter.design/blog/free-user-research-ux-design-starter-kit/) such as [wireframes](https://uxdesign.cc/why-should-product-teams-use-wireframes-more-often-60e34a2bc55): with this kind of tools you can easily find out if it's better to do one choice at a time,  or on contrary to offer the full palette immediately (not to mention that options are not mutually exclusive).

Comment: so one usecases only rightt but with multiple options

Comment: @saladmoe23 That’s it: one use case , in the use-case text documentation the possible options would be described, or an activity diagram could describe the flow for this specific use-case. A modelling alternative would be to add a use-case with an extension dependency (extensions are optional), but this would be overkill and does not seem appropriate here.